# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 11

Tags: java, postgresql, prepared-statement

I have 10 parameters set in the statement with the question marks and provided 10 associated values. At execution, it’s throwing this error “org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 11.” I’m having a similar issue with another table where it’s also asking for an out of range parameter. I can manually run the query against PostGres without any problem. Please see log below, thanks in advance.

```
[DBOperations]:INSERT INTO product.SHIB_RP_MD_PROVIDER(RP_MD_PROVIDER_ID,MD_PROVIDER_TYPE_ID,MD_ID,SRC_ORG_ID,MD_NAME,MD_DESC,PARENT_RP_MD_PROVIDER_ID,LAST_UPDATE_USER,LAST_UPDATE_DATE,SYSTEM_IND,ORG_ID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,date_trunc('second' , now()),?,?)

[DBOperations]:No value specified for parameter 11. org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 11.

[DBOperations] - Index 1 - Value 10042
[DBOperations] - Index 2 - Value 4
[DBOperations] - Index 3 - Value aa
[DBOperations] - Index 4 - Value 2
[DBOperations] - Index 5 - Value aa
[DBOperations] - Index 6 - Value null
[DBOperations] - Index 7 - Value 0
[DBOperations] - Index 8 - Value 1234
[DBOperations] - Index 9 - Value 0
[DBOperations] - Index 10 - Value 2
```

Comment: you actually have 11 parameters. did you put in an extra one by accident?

Answer (score 3):

```
   INSERT INTO dah53idm.SHIB_RP_MD_PROVIDER(RP_MD_PROVIDER_ID,MD_PROVIDER_TYPE_ID,
    MD_ID,SRC_ORG_ID,MD_NAME,
    MD_DESC,PARENT_RP_MD_PROVIDER_ID,
    LAST_UPDATE_USERID,
    LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
    SYSTEM_IND,ORG_ID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,date_trunc('second' , now()),?,?)
```

well answer is pretty obvious . but i'll point it out anyway, you have `11 question marks` which means you are supposed to add `11 values` to execute the query but in your code you are adding `only 10` , hence the exception `"no value specified for 11"`

Comment: I counted only 10 question marks. I'm passing in date_trunc('second' , now()) for one of the columns. Therefore I'm assuming I don't need to put a question mark for that.

Comment: replace that part with a `?` and add values  later.

Comment: dont add values to `9`  add values to `10 and 11` straightaway

Answer (score 0):

assign all the parameters to the values properly

```
for (User user : users) {
    System.out.println("Inserting Data for Userr name" + user.getName());
    jdbcTemplate.update("insert into USERR(Id,Name,Dept,Salary) 
    values(?,?,?,?)",
    preparedStatement -> {
        preparedStatement.setLong(1,user.getId());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getName());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getDept());
        preparedStatement.setLong(4, user.getSalary());

    });
```